# Does mongo atlas support in-memory storage?

Tags: mongodb

Do you know whether Mongo Atlas supports mongo in-memory storage or not?
If so, do we need to purchase Mongo DB enterprise edition license for enabling it or is it coming as part of Atlas itself?

Answer (score 1):

As of today,  [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) does not support in-memory storage engine. MongoDB Atlas only supports MongoDB versions 3.4, 3.6, and 4.0 with the [WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/).

However, you can utilise [MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) with In-Memory storage engine. As it offers more granular control, exposing numerous MongoDB configuration options such as the **storage engine**, startup parameters, and access control options. Cloud Manager also provides the ability to manage MongoDB on the infrastructure of your choice.

MongoDB Cloud Manager is better suited for advanced operations users who require this higher level of control, but Cloud Manager requires users to manage the full lifecycle of their infrastructure.

Please note that [MongoDB In-Memory Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) is part of the MongoDB enterprise edition offerings.